# Automatic New Page based on text

Tags: c#, wpf, pdfsharp, migradoc

Hi there
i had been sucessfully using this great library PDF Sharp.now i wanted to play with some dynamic Stuff so people recomended to switch to Migradoc I did and like its paragraph feature.Now the problem is that when i add long paragraph then new page is not added instead of that there is incomplete text shown(incomplete in sense that text overflows) and i have added a image at the bottom for footer look.how can i do that i enter dynamic text (variable length ) and it just adds the required Number of pages.

My code so far is

```
 XFont font = new XFont("Times New Roman", 12, XFontStyle.Bold);
            XFont fontReg = new XFont("Times New Roman", 12, XFontStyle.Regular);

            // HACK²
            gfx.MUH = PdfFontEncoding.Unicode;
            gfx.MFEH = PdfFontEmbedding.Default;

            string appPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath);
            XImage image = XImage.FromFile(appPath + "/header.png");
            gfx.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);
            //Civil Stamp
            gfx.DrawImage(XImage.FromFile(appPath + "/cStamp.png"), 370, 380);

            gfx.DrawImage(XImage.FromFile(appPath + "/Sp.png"), 230, 380);

            CoverPageHeader();

            Document doc = new Document();
            MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Section sec = doc.AddSection();
            // Add a single paragraph with some text and format information.
            MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Paragraph para = sec.AddParagraph();
            para.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
            para.Format.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
            para.Format.Font.Size = 12;
            para.Format.Font.Color = MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Colors.Black;

            para.AddText("We are pleased to present the attached Document Please review the Agreement and, if acceptable, " +
                "sign one copy and return it to us.  We will sign the copy of the agreement and return one for " +
                "your records.");

            para.AddLineBreak();
            para.AddLineBreak();
            para.AddText(longlongtextString);
            para.AddLineBreak();
            para.AddLineBreak();            
            para.AddText("Sincerely,");

 MigraDoc.Rendering.DocumentRenderer docRenderer = new DocumentRenderer(doc);
            docRenderer.PrepareDocument();

            // Render the paragraph. You can render tables or shapes the same way.
            docRenderer.RenderObject(gfx, XUnit.FromCentimeter(0.7), XUnit.FromCentimeter(9), "18cm", para);

            gfx.DrawString("Kelly Turbin PhD., P.E.-SECB", font, XBrushes.Black, 20, 500);
            gfx.DrawString("Principal", font, XBrushes.Black, 20, 520);
            gfx.DrawString("Project No " + textBoxProjNumber.Text, fontReg, XBrushes.Black, 20,785);

            gfx.DrawImage(XImage.FromFile(appPath + "/AccB.png"), 20, 700);
            gfx.DrawImage(XImage.FromFile(appPath + "/ScreenMagic.png"), 100, 690);
            gfx.DrawImage(XImage.FromFile(appPath + "/Footer.png"), 220, 750);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use RenderObject, instead use RenderDocument and pages will be created automatically as needed.

Sample code here:
http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/HelloMigraDoc-sample.ashx

Comment: there is no option for docRenderer.RenderDocument there are two methods available only RenderObject and RenderPage

Comment: if i change the last lines of the code then nothing is seen in pdf
PdfDocumentRenderer renderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(true, PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfFontEmbedding.Always);
                renderer.Document = doc;
                renderer.RenderDocument();

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to automatically create new pages based on text size, when you are using the [Mix of PDFSharp and MigraDoc](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/MixMigraDocAndPdfSharp-sample.ashx), as it is in the question. The only solution is to use only **MigraDoc** with its **RenderDocument** method.